# How to override iOS dark mode style for datepicker

Tags: ios, datepicker, nativescript, nativescript-vue

[image]

Like you can see the selected value in date picker is white. If I change the date, it won't become visible. This a screenshot of iOS dark mode. Is there a way to override the default styling for that. I tried the following:

```
.date-picker {
   color: #000000;

   .ns-dark & {
     color: #000000;
   }
}
```

[image]

This is how it looks when the background is black

Comment: In general you are suppose to keep your background dark in dark mode. If you don't want to support dark mode, you may opt out from dark mode at once.

Comment: @Manoj Like you can see the TimePicker stays the same in dark mode, I didn't change anything to the TimePicker, but let me update the pictures in dark background mode.

Comment: @manoj is saying that either your app should support dark mode correctly or you should override the traits for your app so that dark mode is disabled.

Comment: I know what he is meaning but the view that you’re seeing is a modal. You can change the backgroundcolor of the modal. So why can I change the color of the datepicker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I couldn't override the color of the Datepicker. I was also not able to override the background color of the modal. 
I needed to add the `<page>` tag to my modal. There I can add a class so I could change the background color during dark mode. So it looks something like this:

```
<Page class="background-color-modal">
    <DockLayout class="modal">
          <FlexboxLayout class="timeDateDetails">
               <time-modal :selected-time="selectedTime" 
                           :time="$props.time" @updateTime="updateTime"/>
          </FlexboxLayout>
     </DockLayout>
</Page>

<style lang="scss" scoped>

    .background-color-modal {
        background-color: $white;
        color: $dark;

        .ns-dark & {
            background-color: $dark-dark;
            color: $dark-white
        }
    }

    .modal {
        background-color: $white;
        color: $dark;

        .ns-dark & {
            background-color: $dark-dark;
            color: $dark-white
        }
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use UIUserInterfaceStyle property **overrideUserInterfaceStyle** of UIViewController to change controller's interface style.

```
class TestViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var datePicker: UIDatePicker!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
            overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .dark
            datePicker.backgroundColor = .black
        } else {
            datePicker.backgroundColor = .white
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In what file do I need to add this?